# Downloading all external and internal javascript files in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want know how to download all external javascripts files and internal javascript code from a webpage. Is there any library or example to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Beautiful Soup](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a widely used library for web scraping in Python.

Here is a simple example that shows how to retrieve the JavaScript sources paths and internal scripts in a page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://example.com/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()) 

sources = []
scripts = []

for script in soup('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'}):
    src = script.get('src')
    if src:  
        sources.append(src)   
    else:  
        scripts.append(script.text)

print scripts
print sources
```

Comment: Thanks Irit, due to my limited reputation, I can't score up your answer. I have to dig more to isolate javascript functions in 'scripts' and externals 'sources' and then wget the 'sources'.